# How do I use wildcard to find a register ignoring spaces in the position of the wildcard in MS Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, wildcard

I have two or more different registers in my database, as follow:

`EMEAFRANKFURTPDEDHuman Resourcesexpat immigrationApplication`

and

`EMEAFRANKFURT NBEUAGITCLS (GUI)Application`

I would like to find any register that is like `EMEAFRANKFURT` but excluding registers with any **space** after the word **FRANKFURT**.

If I use `WHERE [FIELD] IS LIKE "EMEAFRANKFURT*"` it won't ignore the space.
So in summary my question is, how do I ignore the space?

Thank you,

Comment: It'll be expensive in terms of execution time, but you could do: `WHERE [FIELD] IS LIKE "EMEAFRANKFURT*" AND [FIELD] IS NOT LIKE "EMEAFRANKFURT *"`. This would exclude rows with the space.

Comment: Interesting! It worked, so the SQL executes the first where filter and then filter it again using the second condition? Cool! Just an adjustment, I needed to removed the word **IS** before **NOT**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inverse range operator to do it in a single filter operation:

```
[FIELD] LIKE "EMEAFRANKFURT[! ]*"
```

Note that this requires at least one character after `EMEAFRANKFURT`. If that's undesirable, you can use `[FIELD] LIKE "EMEAFRANKFURT[! ]*" Or [FIELD] = "EMEAFRANKFURT"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after thinking about I got the solution.
I used another table that contains the same field and perform a right join and then I used the criteria as follow:

In the left table:
`Like 'EMEAFRANKFURT*'`

In the right table
`Not Like 'EMEAFRANKFURT *'`

So it is ignoring all matches with the left table that contains a *space* after the word **FRANKFURT**.

However, is there any other solution that isn't use a right join?